# Pandas - Concat two dataframes, but if a column is missing in one dataframe, fill that column with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, data-science

I have two dataframes (df1 and df2). They have similar columns, but one of them might have one or two columns missing, because they come from scraping a website that not always returns the same information.
Lets say:
df1

| Index | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 6 |

df2

| Index | Column A | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7 | 9 |
| 1 | 8 | 10 |

My expected result would be:

| Index | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 | NaN | 9 |
| 3 | 8 | NaN | 10 |

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
   Column A  Column B  Column C
0         1       3.0         5
1         2       4.0         6
2         7       NaN         9
3         8       NaN        10
```

Edit: `pd.concat` only works on data with unique indices. If your original dataframes contain duplicate indices, try this:

```
pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I tried this solution and I get this error: 'InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects'

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. What version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: TRY this once: `pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: @Nk03 - Thanks, I was just editing my post to reflect this.

Comment: @not_speshal I am using pandas==1.2.0